# allow specific extension in forms authentication

Tags: asp.net

I am using forms authentication with

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

However, I want to allow all calls made for specific extension say *.abc.

I tried:

```
<location path=".abc">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

but wildcards are not allowed.

How can I allow *.abc calls to work for all users?
Is there any web.config element I can use OR anything I can do in AuthenticateRequest httpmodule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a single file then you can do as following

```
<location path="filename.abc">
```

Otherwise put the files in folder/sub folder architecture and allow them for the anonymous use.

```
<location path="foldername">
```

Comment: I have dynamic files with extension abc.Since they are not physical, I can't put them in a folder. I need all *.abc files to be allowed.

Comment: It was very helpful to fix my problem. I created all dynamic pages inside a dynamic folder and it worked...thanks!